# Strange results using opencv CUDA & BM

Tags: c++, opencv

I hope you can help me to find out why CUDA BM is giving me strange results. I simply want to generate a disparity map of two rectified images. But here is the result:

[image]

And here is the piece of code:

```
Mat img1, img2;
img1 = imread("img1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
img2 = imread("img2.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cuda::GpuMat d_left, d_right;
Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> bm;
bm = cuda::createStereoBM(64, 5);
Mat disp(img1.size(), CV_8U);
cuda::GpuMat d_disp(img1.size(), CV_8U);
d_left.upload(img1);
d_right.upload(img2);
bm->compute(d_right, d_left, d_disp);
cuda::drawColorDisp(d_disp, d_disp, 64);
d_disp.download(disp);
resize(disp, disp, Size(0,0), 0.3, 0.3, 1);
imshow("disparity", disp);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Which part of the result seems strange to you?

Comment: For future reference, please post the code *in the question*.  SO is intended to be a resource for future readers.  When your external code link breaks, the question may become useless.

Comment: Ok - I will edit the post. I expected something like this:http://www.cescg.org/CESCG-2008/papers/BrnoBUT-Klaudiny-Martin/images/DisparityMap-face_global%2Blocal.png

Comment: The disparity map looks a bit noisy and both images are in a way visible in the disparity image (the contours of the right image are red in the disparity image)

Comment: So I can't imagine to get a good pointcloud from that. The question is now if I am doing something wrong? For example not a good calibration..but my reprojection error is quiet good..0.2 and the images seem to be well rectified. Or is this a typical result for bm and other algorithms will provide better results?

Comment: Or here an other example for a disparity map generated with opencv bm.. Compared with mine..mine is a random noise image   http://www.google.de/imgres?client=tablet-android-lenovo&sa=X&espv=1&sboxchip=Bilder&biw=1280&bih=640&tbm=isch&tbnid=JuuUYt0tg5ntPM%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.martinperis.com%2F2012%2F01%2F3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html&docid=K8s2zrzJ1r12cM&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-gN5cvUimyfs%2FTwbJ6XbrYjI%2FAAAAAAAAAcA%2FDauqmx8JCSU%2Fs1600%2Fdisparity-image.jpg&w=640&h=480&ei=0eMJU9mwOoSHswba_4DwCA&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=2&start=15&ndsp=15&ved=0CGoQrQMwFA

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it is a matter of display and image depth (Unsigned short , float, etc.)
after download to disp normalize it between 0 to 1, and then multiply by 255 and convert to uint8

```
Mat displayMat;
double minVal, maxVal;
minMaxLoc(disp, &minVal, &maxVal);
disp = 255.*(disp - minVal)/(maxVal - minVal);
disp.convertTo(displayMat, CV_8U);
imshow("disparity", displayMat)
```